# how to save custom ModelForm fields in django

Tags: django, forms

i have custom fields in ModelForm and there is no any values on save. im just confuse what to use in `view.py` to save with data

form.py

```
class AddCityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    duration = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
        'style': 'background-color: #FAF9F9', 'class': 'mb-3, form-check-inline'}), choices=DURATION_CHOICES)

    country = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
        'style': 'background-color: #FAF9F9', 'class': 'mb-3, form-check-inline'}), choices=CITY_CHOICE)

    something = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'style': 'background-color: #FAF9F9', 'class': 'mb-3'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Cities
        exclude = ['city', 'duration', 'something']
```

view.py

```
def add_city(request):
    data = dict()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = AddCityForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.city = request.POST.get('country')
            form.duration = request.POST.get('dur')
            form.something = request.POST.get('something')
            form = form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Test for Added Successfully')
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = AddCityForm()
    context = dict(form=form)
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('cites/modal_1.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

can any one help with this ?

Comment: Strange , looks like is working now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code is working, i have no idea why did not before i asked this question but i will keep this if any one look for similar question